# tf.cond on a variable. FailedPreconditionError in tf.global_variables_initializer()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am running into  FailedPreconditionError error in `tf.global_variables_initializer()`. I have zeroed-in on the following part of the code to be the culprit:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.global_step = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), trainable=False, shape=(), name='global_step')
    ...
    step_rampup_value = self.step_rampup(self.global_step, self.rampup_length)

def step_rampup(self, global_step, rampup_length):
    result = tf.cond(global_step < rampup_length,
                     lambda: tf.constant(0.0),
                     lambda: tf.constant(1.0))
    return tf.identity(result, name="step_rampup")
session.run(tf.global_variables_initilizer())
```

`self.global_step` is to be incremented by `1` by optimizer at each iteration. It's value has to change. So, that is the behavior I want.

Error message:

```
FailedPreconditionError ...
506         with tf.Session(graph=highgraph) as session:
--> 507             session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
...
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value global_step
 [[node global_step/read (defined at NML_U/sNeural.py:103)  = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](global_step)]]
```

Why is that part of the code is culprit?
Because, The following code works

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.global_step = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), trainable=False, shape=(), name='global_step')
    ...
    step_rampup_value = self.step_rampup(self.global_step, self.rampup_length)

def step_rampup(self, global_step, rampup_length):
    result = tf.cond(global_step.initialized_value() < rampup_length,
                     lambda: tf.constant(0.0),
                     lambda: tf.constant(1.0))
    return tf.identity(result, name="step_rampup")
session.run(tf.global_variables_initilizer())
```

but that will evaluate the conditional with the initialized value of `self.global_step(=0)` each time which is not the intended behavior

Also,

This code works as well:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    self.global_step = tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), trainable=False, shape=(), name='global_step')
    self.global_step = tf.assign(self.global_step,0.)
    ...
    step_rampup_value = self.step_rampup(self.global_step, self.rampup_length)

def step_rampup(self, global_step, rampup_length):
    result = tf.cond(global_step < rampup_length,
                     lambda: tf.constant(0.0),
                     lambda: tf.constant(1.0))
    return tf.identity(result, name="step_rampup")
session.run(tf.global_variables_initilizer())
```

But (maybe) this will again not lead to the dependency on `global_step` but  instead on assign op which will keep assigning `0` to `self.global_step`

How do I go about achieving the behavior?

Comment: Have you tried `tf.variables_initializer` ? Also consider adding full code

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide the full code, so I can only guess that you are perhaps calling `tf.global_variables_initializer()` *before* `__init__()`. Indeed the former will not initialize variables that are created after it has been called.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, the issue was something else. Can be summarized by https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8172 . I was wrong in identifying the source of the issue. I was using result of step_rampup to compute adam_beta_2 for my adam optimizer and adam was not able to initialize its parameters because global_step was not initialized at the time of runtime trying to initialize adam's parameters and result of step_rampup is tf.cond(...) on global_step